# Too much html element slow down jquery

Tags: jquery, html, performance

I have a js script to get a datafeed and built some div according to the response text.

I have already used web worker and ajax to split the read datafeed and build html code process.

However while I append the html to my container, it becomes slow (let say 18000's div)

Then I change the method to append the 200 div for scroll to down of my container.

It becomes very fast, but while all items render, the other process start to become slow,
for example if I make the container show and hide, it is pretty slow.

I found another solution is to use z-index, it makes the show hide process much faster.

However, while I need to change the container content, it becomes slow again.

Any idea or solution?

Comment: Having 18000 elemenmts in a page is a really bad idea. You are on track with showing only 200 elements at a time, but you would need to control your pagination logic as well so that when you switch to new elements you process only 200 elements and not all of them

Comment: but i have already apply the process append 200 for each scroll, since the container must use scroll bar for pagination (according to my boss requirement)

Comment: The speed is not bcoz of too much of HTML. I believe, you will be iterating the responseText data inside some for loop. jQuery starts atonce the dom is build. The number of HTML does not have any adverse effect. Check you responseText logic or you may be running too many ajax calls

Comment: or i need to check the scroll list, if it is already scroll down to > 200, then remove previous item? but it will become slow , if ppl keep scroll down and up

Comment: madhairsilence, the speed is reli becoz of html, the ajax will not effect the page, since i use html5 web worker! the problem is if u try to apply 18000 div into a main div by jquery, u will see the problem

Comment: One important note is event handling, You need to use delegated event handling model `on('event', 'selector', 'handler')

Comment: Did you consider using a control to show your data? For example, [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/) can easily handle [500,000 rows](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-optimizing-dataview.html), and can [display custom templates](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example8-alternative-display.html).

Comment: Arun P Johny , wat are u talking about?

Comment: Kobi, thx, the grid idea is quite good, it is not diplay 500000 record at once, but only display the record which the position is within the scroll range

Answer (score 3):

Performing as many changes as possible outside of the live DOM structure will improve the performance.To know more about take the look at the [How to improve the performance of your java script in your page?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-java-script-in-your-page/)

Comment: actually even i only do a process for document.getElementById("xxxx").innerHTML = "" will become slow, if there is 18000 div on ur page

Comment: Did you Gothrough all the refs specified in the article

Answer (score 1):

I have been in this similar situation, where I was adding lot of child's to a node in a tree.

**Problems**

1. The page was slow.
2. Rendering of elements were slow,Sometimes even JS crashes in IE.

**Solutions**

1. I created a upper threshold of the number elements that will be present in a DOM at one instance. Lets say initially there are 500 elements,then there is another ajax request that will be fetching around 500 nodes so I would  clear some element. It can help if you can manage the clearing scenarios.
2. No inline CSS Styles, It will look what this thing will create difference but keep all the Styling in CSS classes improves performance.
3. Defining an appropriate HTML Structure Like not keeping any dangling divs,spans etc.
4. attaching event handlers through proper delegation like 'on'.

There are lot of things that can be done tom improve this. If you can post a jsfiddle for this will certainly help.

Comment: SlickGrid can easily handle

Answer (score 0):

The question has solved
SlickGrid can easily handle